# Disable certificate on requests session in python

Tags: python, kodi

I am a total newb on python and I would really appreciate the help on this problem.

I am using `requests` to get files from a cloud service in a `kodi` `addon`.

I have tried to put `verify=False` on the `get` but it didn't work

```
s = requests.Session()

file = s.get(api_base + '/api/v2/mounts/' + mount['id'] + '/files/download', params = {'path': foldername + '/' + file['name']}, verify=False).json()['link']
```

I ge the following error:

```
SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install requests extra security package.

```
pip install requests[security]
```

This will install required SSL packages mentioned [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning).

Comment: I don't think it will work, I need to disable them because Kodi comes with build in python